# No tag "link" defined in tag library imported with prefix "h" | tomcat | eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jsf-2

I was working in Netbeans IDE and switched to Eclipse.

I created a simple JSF 2.0 based using wizard in eclipse. The complete file is this.

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
<h1>Hi, This is my JSF 2. Applicaiton</h1>
<br />
Click <h:link outcome="UserLogin">here</h:link> to go to login
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

When I deploted this app in tomcat 7.0 server, I am getting the following error message,

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(14,6) No tag "link" defined in tag library imported with prefix "h"
```

In my IDE also I can see the

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `<h:link>` was new in JSF 2.0 and didn't exist in JSF 1.x. This error can thus have the following causes:

1. You've actually JSF 1.x libraries in your `/WEB-INF/lib`, not JSF 2.0 libraries.
2. Your `faces-config.xml` is declared as JSF 1.x instead of JSF 2.0. Ensure that it is declared conform JSF 2.0 spec.

   ```
   <faces-config
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
       version="2.0">
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A few quick questions:

1. Where is your JSF library located?
2. I think you meant more after:In my
   IDE also I can see the which leads
   into.
3. Eclipse is usually pretty good
       at being able to find your tag
       libraries. Is it complaining about
       the use of these libraries in your
       jsp editor page?

Let us know some more info about your setup first.

I'll throw out the obvious solution: You've lost the reference to your JSF jar(jsf-impl.jar). Including it in your Tomcat lib folder should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the middle of this problem too, I would like to find some solution, but I don't manage. As I found you are at the same step like me.

If you use facelets then you are able to see that tag, instead if you use normal "JSF" it gives the error as you mentioned.

You could try this procedure to solve your problem.

1. Try to understand how to configure facelets on your web app. For example for my webapp files that ends with `*.xhtml` are processed by facelets engine.
   Rename file to `*.xhtml`.
2. Prepend this

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   ```

   and

   ```
   <html
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   ```

   instead of normal html.
3. Remove any of the directive

   ```
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
   ```

Detailed instructions can be found here: http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/MigrateFromJspToFacelets

Then you should be able to process `h:link`.